# Downgrading to PHP 5.3 on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I'm on the verge of giving up with this.
I have a client running some code compatible with PHP 5.3 and below.
I am trying to figure out a way to install Nginx with PHP 5.3.

I have a LEMP set up running PHP 5.5
I followed this tutorial [here](https://stavrovski.net/blog/build-and-install-php-5329-from-source-on-an-ubuntu-1404-lts-server) that allowed me to rebuild PHP 5.3

And everything ran successfully, but what do I do after I've built it?

Okay so I've installed PHP 5.3
PHP 5.5 is still running on my web server

I've run this:

```
USER=root
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=15  
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000  

/usr/bin/env -- - USER=$USER PATH=/usr/bin PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=$PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=$PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS /opt/PHP-5.3/etc/bin/php & 127.0.0.1:9001
```

to try and get it to work but I have no idea what I'm doing to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you install PHP 5.5? According to that tutorial of yours, you should install 5.3:

> #### DOWNLOAD PHP
>
> Now let's download the latest PHP 5.3.29 archive from some [PHP mirror](http://php.net/mirrors.php) using the commands below:
>
> ```
> PHP_VERSION=5.3.29
> wget -O /var/tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.bz2 \
>   http://bg2.php.net/get/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
> ```

You need to specify exactly what you're doing, what the expected result is, and what the actual result is.

Comment: I had installed a LAMP with PHP 5.5 pre-installed. I did the PHP 5.3 rebuild afterwards.

Comment: @Matthew so, everything's OK, no? **What is your question?**

Comment: My problem is that Nginx is still running on PHP 5.6 (which is to be expected) now how do I tell Nginx to run PHP 5.3?

Comment: @Matthew http://marcelog.github.io/articles/configure_nginx_php_5.3_5.2_fastcgi.html

Comment: You see the problem is I am pretty new at this type of thing, I've never had to set up something like this before so it confuses the hell out of me. I understand the JUST of that link but other than that I am super confused.
My file paths differ to the ones stated in that link. And some of the files don't seem to even exist.

Comment: @Matthew setting this up isn't particularly easy. But if you want to continue, please edit your question to explain exactly what problems you encounter.